# OpenCV display two video (PiP) with the highest frame rate of both videos

Tags: c++, opencv, real-time

I want to display two videos, from two differents real time feeds with different frame rates, on the same image. And I would like that my resulting video keep the highest frame rate.

Problem is, as *cv::VideoCapture.imread()* is a blocking operation, I'm currently limited by the lowest frame rate. And so the video with a higher frame rate is jerky (see my code bellow)

```
static cv::Mat frame;
static cv::Mat smallframe;
cv::Mat processedFrame;

begin = clock();
while(isReading)
{
    _capture1 >> frame;
    _capture2 >> smallframe;
    if (!frame.data)
    {
        isReading = false;
        _capture1.release();
    }
    else if(!smallframe.data)
    {
        _capture2.release();
    }
    else
    {
        if (frame.channels()== 3)
        {
            cv::cvtColor(frame, processedFrame, CV_BGR2BGRA);
        }
        else if (frame.channels() == 1)
        {
            cv::cvtColor(frame, processedFrame, CV_GRAY2BGRA);
        }
        else
        {
            frame.copyTo(processedFrame);
        }
        if (smallframe.channels()== 3)
        {
            cv::cvtColor(smallframe, smallframe, CV_BGR2BGRA);
        }
        else if (smallframe.channels() == 1)
        {
            cv::cvtColor(smallframe, smallframe, CV_GRAY2BGRA);
        }

        cv::Mat resizedSmall;
        float wPipRatio = (float) processedFrame.cols / (float) smallframe.cols;
        float hPipRatio = (float) processedFrame.rows / (float) smallframe.rows;
        int pipCols, pipRows;
        if (wPipRatio < hPipRatio)
        {
            pipCols = processedFrame.cols * _pipRatio;
            pipRows = processedFrame.rows * _pipRatio * (wPipRatio/hPipRatio);
        }
        else
        {
            pipCols = processedFrame.cols * _pipRatio * (hPipRatio/wPipRatio);
            pipRows = processedFrame.rows * _pipRatio;
        }

        cv::resize(smallframe, resizedSmall, cv::Size(pipCols, pipRows));

        // Define roi area (it has small image dimensions).
        cv::Rect roiSV = cv::Rect(processedFrame.cols - pipCols,
                                  processedFrame.rows - pipRows,
                                  pipCols,
                                  pipRows);

        cv::Mat subView;
        if(0 <= roiSV.x && 0 <= roiSV.width &&
                0 <= roiSV.y && 0 <= roiSV.height &&
                roiSV.x + roiSV.width <= processedFrame.cols &&
                roiSV.y + roiSV.height <= processedFrame.rows)
        {
            subView = processedFrame(roiSV);
            resizedSmall.copyTo(subView);
        }
    }
}
```

(with _capture1 and _capture2 two cv::VideoCapture)

Do you have any idea to get around this limitation ?

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is thread. Process each video in it's own thread.

Comment: @DimChtz You must be right, Honestly I'm not really at ease with threads so I was hoping to find another solution, but I guess I will have to get into it.